# Strange behavior of String tokenizer in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, strtok

I have written the following program to resolve a path to several directory names

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *
tokenizer(char *path, char **name){
  char s[300];
  char *buffer;
  memcpy(s, path, strlen(path)+1);
  printf("%s\n",s);    // PROBLEM
  int i=0;
  while(s[i] == '/'){
    i++;
  }
  if (i == strlen(path)){
    return NULL;
  }
  *name = strtok_r(s, "/", &buffer);
  return buffer;
}

int main(void){
  char str[300];
  char *token, *p;
  scanf("%s",str);
  p = tokenizer(str, &token);
  if (p != NULL)
    printf("%s\n",token);
  else
    printf("Nothing left\n");
  while((p=tokenizer(p, &token)) != NULL){
    printf("%s\n",token);
  }
}
```

Output of the above program

```
Input: a/b/c
Output: a/b/c
a/b/c
a
b/c
b
c
c
```

If I comment the line labelled PROBLEM

```
Input: a/b/c
Output: Some garbage value
```

Can somebody explain me the reason for this strange behavior?

Note:
I have realised that `s` is a stack allocated variable and it ceases to exist in function `main()` but why does the program works when I use `printf()` ?

Comment: If I compile your program, I get a warning in the bottommost `while` line. Better look into that first.

Comment: @MrLister I don't get any warnings while compiling the program. What options are you specifying to the gcc compiler?

Comment: why memcpy instead of strcpy? (you rely on strlen anyway)

Comment: @gibraltar gcc 4.3 without options gives me `test.c:31: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘tokenizer’ from incompatible pointer type`

Comment: @MrLister I have corrected the mistake. Sorry for that.

Comment: >why does the program works when I use printf() ? because the memcpy before using the printf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what geekasaur says:

`strtok_r`'s 3rd parameter is used incorrectly, in two ways:
1. It should be initialized to NULL before the first call.
2. It shouldn't be used in any way (you return it to the caller). It should only be passed to another `strtok_r` call.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning a pointer into a stack-allocated string (`buffer` points into `s`); `s`'s memory ceases to be meaningful after `tokenize` returns.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this

```
char s[300];
char *buffer;
...
*name = strtok_r(s, "/", &buffer);
return buffer;
```

Here `buffer` is a pointer to a `s[300]` position. `s[300]` is a function local variable allocated on the stack when the function is called and destroyed when the function returns.
So you are not returning a valid pointer, you cannot use that pointer out of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the observations that you're returning a pointer to a local variable, I think it's worth noting that your `tokenizer` is almost 100% pointless.

Most of what your `tokenizer` does is skip across any leading `/` characters before calling `strtok_r` -- but you're passing '/' as the delimiter character to `strtok_r`, which will automatically skip across any leading delimiter characters on it own.

Rather simpler code suffices to print out the components of a path without the delimiters:

```
char path[] = "a/b/c";
char *pos = NULL;

char *component = strtok_r(path, "/", &pos);
while (NULL != component) { 
    printf("%s\n", component);
    component = strtok_r(NULL, "/", &pos);
}
```

Comment: I know how to tokenize strings. I know I can adopt the above implementation. I am asking why is my program behaving strangely in case of printf. And tokenizer is just a test program. I am implementing a file system with linux like directory structure where I need to traverse directories one by one to reach the final inode.

Comment: @gibraltar: So if you know how to tokenize strings, why did you ask about the behavior of code you knew had undefined behavior?

Comment: My question is why does the program behaves correctly in case of printf() ?

Comment: @gibraltar: "**undefined behavior** behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
for which this International Standard imposes no requirements" That may (and often does) include seeming to work correctly, at least under some poorly defined conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char*
token(char * path, char ** name){

    static char * obuffer = NULL;
    char * buffer = NULL, * p, * q;

    if(path == NULL) {
        buffer = realloc(buffer, strlen(obuffer) + 1);
        p = obuffer;
    } else {
        buffer = malloc(257);
        p = path;
    }

    if(!buffer) return NULL;
    q = buffer; 

    if(!p || !*p) return NULL;

    while(*p != '\0') {
          if(*p == '/') { 
            p++; /* remove the / from string. */
            break;
          }
          *q ++ = *p++;
    }

    *q ++ = '\0';
    obuffer = p;
    *name = buffer;

    return buffer;
}

int main(void)
{

    char * s = "foo/baa/hehehe/";
    char * name = NULL;
    char * t = token(s, &name);
    while(t) {
        printf("%s\n", name);
        t = token(NULL, &name);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the output:

```
foo
baa
hehehe
```

But you are basically "reinventing the wheel" of [`strtok()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strtok.html) function..